# Removing extra node in serializing object to XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have following object model

```
public class BIDbObject
{
    // some methods and properties here 

    public BIDbColumns DbColumns { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("root")]
public class BIDbObjects
{
    // some methods and properties here 

    [XmlArray("dbobjects")]
    [XmlArrayItem("dbobject")]
    public List<BIDbObject> DbObjects { get; set; }
}

public class BIDbColumn
{
    // some methods and properties here 

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
}

public class BIDbColumns
{
    // some methods and properties here 

    [XmlArray("columns")]
    [XmlArrayItem("column")]
    public List<BIDbColumn> DbColumns { get; set; }
}
```

I serialize `BIDbObjects` class and get below XML

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <dbobjects>
    <dbobject database="Crius" schema="dbo" name="rptAgedPhase3ColLoginReceived" type="T">
      <DbColumns>
        <columns>
          <column name="LoanNum" />
          <column name="BACLOAN_ID" />
          <column name="Unfunded" />
          <column name="RoutingType" />
          <column name="DivAbbrev" />
          <column name="BranchNum" />
          <column name="BranchSatelliteNum" />
          <column name="ClosedCd" />
          <column name="AS400PhaseCd" />
          <column name="RgnNum" />
          <column name="ReceivedDt" />
          <column name="TreasBankPortfolioFlagBit" />
          <column name="TreasBankDestType" />
          <column name="TreasuryBankDestTypeDesc" />
        </columns>
      </DbColumns>
    </dbobject>
    ........
```

I need to get rid of `DbColumns` in the XML

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <dbobject database="Crius" schema="dbo" name="rptAgedPhase3ColLoginReceived" type="T">
    <DbColumns>  <---- this one
      <columns>
      .....
```

Preferably using XML attributes. Thanks for help!

Comment: Change [XmlArray("columns")] to [XmlElement("columns")].  You don't need XmlArrayItem.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I'm almost there. How I can make it to store <columns> instead of <DbColumns> ?

Comment: if you post your answer I'll mark it. thank you!

Comment: change `public BIDbColumns DbColumns { get; set; }` to `public BIDbColumns Columns { get; set; }` and remove this attribute in `[XmlArray("columns")]` in BIDbColumns class that will give your desired XML output

Comment: @FLICKER Let me know if that works

Comment: The string in XmlElement will override the the property name.

Comment: @jdweng, You are right. I figured it out couple of minutes ago. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with below changes. I post it here for future references. Thank's `@jdweng` for help.

```
public class BIDbObject
{
    // some methods and properties here 

    [XmlElement("columns")]
    public BIDbColumns DbColumns { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("root")]
public class BIDbObjects
{
    // some methods and properties here 

    [XmlArray("dbobjects")]
    [XmlArrayItem("dbobject")]
    public List<BIDbObject> DbObjects { get; set; }
}

public class BIDbColumn
{
    // some methods and properties here 

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
}

public class BIDbColumns
{
    // some methods and properties here 

    [XmlElement("column")]
    public List<BIDbColumn> DbColumns { get; set; }
}
```